# Safari 9 Not Showing SVG Pinned Tab Icon

Tags: svg, safari, osx-elcapitan

I created a new pinned-tab icon for Safari 9 on El Capitan [as documented by Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html) but I can't seem to get Safari to actually show it when I pin my tab.

Here's the line in my header:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://towatchlist.com/img/twl.svg" color="red">
```

Safari does show the image just fine when I follow [the link to the SVG file](https://towatchlist.com/img/twl.svg), but the pinned tab icon still shows the auto-generated letter image even after reloads and pin/unpin etc.

I tried opening up GitHub's SVG (which is working) and copying the general markup there but that didn't fix things either.  I also poked through the Safari console briefly but didn't see it even attempting to land the SVG file.

Any suggestions on how to even debug this or ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like Safari is aggressively caching (even the absence of) these icons. Found [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/974910) over on Super User:

> Delete the contents of the following folder:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Safari/Template Icons
> ```
>
> And then restart Safari.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was probably a cache issue, but didn't know about the new `Template Icons` directory.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Shaun! That saved me some time. I realized, the most reliable way of getting rid of the cache is to quit Safari, then delete the Folder-Contents and restart Safari. Somehow it seemed to me thought, that there's a minimum Time which needs to elapse until Safari will go out and fetch an uncached resource again…

Comment: If you use [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/), it's a different folder: `rm -r ~/Library/SafariTechnologyPreview/Template\ Icons/`

Comment: New year, new stuff. For some reason, my `~/Library/Safari` doesn't have a folder called "Template Icons". It DOES have a "Touch Icons" folder, but no Template Icons. Is this new for v9.1.2?

Comment: Nope: The folder is created after the first time you pin a site that actually works. (Like Facebook.com). Derp!